# parse deployment on heroku and using android

Tags: android, parsing, heroku

I have been trying to build my android app and deploying my parse server on heroku. After deployment when I test it I get "I dream of being a website" which is what I am supposed to get when I run the web application and it seems all is fine. However, when I start my android application which upon creation tries to insert data into my database, it fails and nothing goes through. This is a picture of what I get in logcat in my android studio: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4GvS.png)

Same exact steps worked for other people but it still wnt work for me.

Thank you.

Comment: I also used this code to reference my application information in heroku
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

   
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .applicationId("moudis2048uj")
            .clientKey("mfrewinf23400")
            .server("https://moudis.herokuapp.com/parse/")
    .build()
    );

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.  I have an Angular app also connected to a Parse Heroku application, and it is working well, but the Android version is not working.    I'm going to keep looking around.  I'll let you know if I find anything

Comment: Yes please if there is a solution let me know as soon as possible. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

just found a solution to the problem. Visit the following link: 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-a-parse-server-to-heroku

then click on deploy to heroku. Things should work fine! enjoy :)